# displaying image in a jQuery popup div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This question is very similar to one I asked last week, however, using the answers I got does not seem to work for me now.  I'm trying to retrieve images associated with a certain popup div.  So far, if I place the image with the associated text within a hidden class, I'm able to pull the image.  However, this requires me to place the image on the page twice.  I would like to only place it once.  I know this is confusing, but basically, I'm wanting to pull an image from a parent node and place it into a popup div.  Here's what I have so far that works.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>.</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/desktop.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/init.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home / About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="work.html">Work Experience</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
            <div id="content">
                <div class="example">
                    <img src="images/army.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <img src="images/army.jpg" />
                        <p>I began my Active Duty career in July of 2002, 3 months after graduating high school.  I had always wanted to join the military as a child and made my final decision after the September 11, 2001 attack on the World Trade Center.  I went to 9 weeks of Basic Training in Ft. Sill Oklahoma.  A week after graduating, I moved across the base to the Field Artillery Training school, where I spent 8 weeks learning to be a Fire Direction Specialist(FDC).  After my training, I was sent to Ft. Lewis Washington where I continued to operate as an FDC with I Corps Field Artillery.  I was quickly given the opportunity to add the Forward Observer MOS to my job title.  While with my unit, I excelled in learning the Advanced Field Artillery Tactical Data Systems(AFATDS) and was given the role of senior AFATDS operator and instructor.  Even though I was a lower rank than most members of my unit at that time, I was given the task of teaching my peers, as well as my superior Officers, and Non-Commissioned Officers in proceedures and operations of an AFATDS machine.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="example">
                    <img src="images/reserve.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <img src="images/reserve.jpg" />
                        <p>Reserves</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="example">
                    <img src="images/gsu.png" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <img src="images/gsu.png" />
                        <p>Georgia Southern</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="example">
                    <img src="images/twc.png" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <img src="images/twc.png" />
                        <p>The Weather Chanel</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="example">
                    <img src="images/fsi.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <img src="images/fsi.jpg" />
                        <p>FlightSafety International</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="example">
                    <img src="images/freelance.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <img src="images/freelance.jpg" />
                        <p>Freelance</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-color: #757575;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

header{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 65px;
    top: -68px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px inset #DDAA00;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 0;
}

nav{
    position: absolute;
    height: 55px;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    color: #DDAA00;
}

nav ul{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 13px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:link{
    color: #DDAA00;
}

nav ul li a:visited{
    color: #757575;
}

nav ul li ul{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

nav ul li ul li{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 68px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

#content{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    top: 75px;
    left: 15%;
    right: 20%;
    font-size: 16pt;
    z-index: 0;
}

#imageHolder{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    z-index: 0;
}

#imageBorder{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 50px 10px #757575 inset;
    z-index: 1;
}

#imageHolder img{
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 150px;
}

#content p{
    text-align: justify;
}

.example{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 25px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 145px;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    z-index: 0;
}

.example img{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
    z-index: 0;
}

.example p{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#popup{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 10%;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    bottom: 10%;
    background-color: #757575;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 25px #000000;
    z-index: 10;
}

#mask{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: -68px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 0.75;
    z-index: 9;
}

.popImgHolder{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 25%;
    background-color: red;
    width: 50%;
    height: 45%;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

.popImgHolder img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.popTxtHolder{
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 55%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

.popTxtHolder p{
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.description{
    display: none;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wrapper').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#wrapper').append('<div id="popup"><div class="popImgHolder"></div><div class="popTxtHolder"></div></div>');
    $('.example').append('<p>Click here to read about my experience<p>');

    $("html").niceScroll();
    var popTxtHolder = $('.popTxtHolder');

    $('.example p').on('click', function(){
        var text = $(this).prev('.description').find('p').text();
        var images = $(this).prev('.description').find('img').attr('src');
        $('.popImgHolder').html('<img src="' +images +'" />');
        $('<p>' +text +'</p>').appendTo('.popTxtHolder');
        $('#popup, #mask').show();
        popTxtHolder.niceScroll({cursorwidth: '2px'});
    })

    $('#popup, #mask').click(function(){
        $('#popup, #mask').hide();
        $('.popTxtHolder, .popImgHolder').children().remove();
    })
})
```

Here's a pen for what I would like to do.  (Notice the images in the html are placed in the parent class of '.example' and not in the child class of '.description'.

http://codepen.io/RobbyT15/pen/EIueF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to

> pull an image from a parent node and place it into a popup div

in your code:

```
var images = $('.example').find('img').attr('src');
$('.popImgHolder').html('<img src="' +images +'" />');
```

you need to do this instead:

```
var image = $(this).parents('.example').find('img:first-child');
image.appendTo('.popImgHolder');
```